# How to get a file from the Amazon S3?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm trying to write and download the file to Amazon S3. The file is loaded but I can not get it back:

```
public function putFile() 
{
    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');

    $url = 'https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p720x720/12631558_953568381347717_3978737099026165391_n.jpg?oh=9e14f5ea6f8e3a3fc8ffa07095d4c766&oe=57321C9D&__gda__=1463610491_c1f275837b7f5b4d2041597a3d7bb9c8';        
    $file = file_get_contents($url);

    $s3->put('upload/test/file.jpg', $file);        
}

public function getFile() 
{
    $contents = $s3->get('upload/test/file.jpg');        
    dd($contents);
}
```

if I call getFile() function, I got this error:

```
FileNotFoundException in FilesystemAdapter.php line 58:
upload/test/file.jpg
```

my Bucket permission:

```
Grantee: mgalex (List, Update/Delete, View Permissions, Edit Permissions)
Grantee: Any Authentificated AWS User (List, Update/Delete, View Permissions)
```

file is created with permissions:

```
Grantee: mgalex (Open/Download, View Permissions, Edit Permissions)
```

Problem with file permissions. If I set up manually permission to file "Any Authentificated AWS User", the code works. Tell me, what should I do, not to create manually permission for each file?
My settings in filesystem.php is correct. What can be wrong?
Please, help.

Comment: have you checked [CORS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)??

Comment: how to do it? In code or command line?

Comment: check this link here - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing/ and here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: CORS is set standard